# UICollectionViewCell reflection - appropriate time for taking the cells' snapshot image

Tags: uicollectionview, snapshot, uicollectionviewcell

I'd like to add reflection to my collection view's cells. I have the method that creates a reflection, but I don't know the correct time to create the snapshot.

I have tried doing it in the collection view's -viewWillAppear:, but the cell's contentView has zero-sized frames for its subviews. I have also tried taking the snapshot during the cell's -layoutSubviews, but the subview frames are still 0.

At what point is the cell's layout set so I can take the snapshot?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the zero size frames in the cell's `layoutSubviews` (after calling `[super layoutSubviews]`, of course). Can you post your view controller & custom cell source code? Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: I'm using Auto Layout. I have created a github repo, here is the URL: https://github.com/bolchisbolchis/reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snapshot should be taken after the cell has been added to the collection view, *and* after the cell has been dequeued by the collection view data source. This ensures the snapshot will be up to date, containing the cell's content view at the correct moment (when it's about to be added to the collection view, and after it has just been dequeued):

`CollectionViewCell.m`

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [self updateSnapshotImage];
}
```

`CollectionViewController.m`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell updateSnapshotImage];
    return cell;
}
```